# OpenCL kernel outputs NaN instead of double

Tags: c, opencl

I'm currently in the process of learning parallel programming and have decided to code a simple N-body simulation using OpenCL. I've hit a dead end while trying to program the kernel:

```
__kernel void nbody_kernel (__global double* x_in, __global double* y_in, __global double* z_in,
                            __global double* x_out, __global double* y_out, __global double* z_out,
                            __global double* v_x, __global double* v_y, __global double* v_z,
                            __global double* m, int n) {
    int id = get_group_id(0)*get_local_size(0)+get_local_id(0);

    if (id < n) {
        double dx, dy, dz;
        double invr, force;

        double ax, ay, az;
        ax = ay = az = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            dx = x_in[j] - x_in[id];
            dy = y_in[j] - y_in[id];
            dz = z_in[j] - z_in[id];

            invr = 1.0 / sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + eps); 
            force = kappa*m[j]*invr*invr*invr; 

            ax += force*dx;
            ay += force*dy;
            az += force*dz;
        }

        x_out[id] = x_in[id] + v_x[id]*dt + 0.5*ax*dt*dt;
        y_out[id] = y_in[id] + v_y[id]*dt + 0.5*ay*dt*dt;
        z_out[id] = z_in[id] + v_z[id]*dt + 0.5*az*dt*dt;

        v_x[id] += ax*dt;
        v_y[id] += ay*dt;
        v_z[id] += az*dt;
    }
}
```

Upon running the above code the x_out/y_out/z_out values appear to be NaN (at least printf seems to think so).

I've diagnosed the issue down to the for loop: if I use a constant (e.g. 2) the kernel runs as expected. The problem only seems to appear when using a variable (either __constant or an argument).

What exactly am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Oh, and in case it's important: I'm running OpenCL 1.1.

EDIT 2: I've already checked that the "n" argument gets passed correctly.

EDIT 3: The constants used in the calculation are defined and initialized in the .cl file as follows:

```
__constant double kappa = 1;
__constant double eps = 0.0001;
__constant double dt = 0.1;
```

I'm creating and passing data buffers like this:

```
d_x0 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, num * sizeof(double), NULL, &status);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, d_x0, CL_TRUE, 0, num * sizeof(double), x_in, 0, NULL, NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &d_x0);
```

As for the n, I'm using:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 10, sizeof(cl_int), &num);
```

EDIT 4: I've played around and if I define the acceleration as `ax = force*dx;` it seems to work properly. Could there be an issue with ax/ay/az not being set to 0 before the program reaches the `ax += force*dx;`?

Comment: What are the buffer settings? write/read only? No setting? USE_HOST_PTR or similar? You could have used int id=get_global_id(0) anyway. Also invr = 1.0 / sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + eps) where did you init the epsilon?

Comment: @huseyin Thank you for commenting. I've edited my question with the relevant information.

Comment: Have you checked that all your inputs are properly initialized? Can a situation arise where the square root is attempted on a negative number? Also OpenCL has the inverse square root function, rsqrt.

Comment: @Steinin I can't believe it... rsqrt solved the problem. Any ideas on why that would happen? I was adding squares so negative number roots shouldn't have been a problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, if dx dy and dz are 0. Then the square root will be 0, and the division will be NaN. With rsqrt() you multiply, so the output may not give a NaN. Tipically it will be implemented as pow(x, -0.5) giving 1 when the input is 0. In addition, if only one value gives NaN then the sum will be a NaN.

Comment: @DarkZeros I thought adding `eps` (which is always bigger than 0) would solve that. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Strongly suspect an element of `x_in[]`, `y_in[]` or `z_in[]` is not initialized properly.

Comment: Steinin you are a godsend. Thank you so much!